# The right way to apply GroupBy extension method with aggregate function

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have this simple model.

```
public class Room
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? postSubjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("postSubjectId")]
    public PostSubject postSubject { get; set; }

    public string MemberId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MemberId")]
    public AppUser Member { get; set; }

}
```

Basically I need to get Grouped `postSubjectId` along with `MemberId.Count()` , I know it's easy .. but it never comes with the expected result.

I made this simple GroupBy query

```
var mmbrs = _context.Rooms
    .Select(g => new { id = g.postSubjectId, mmbrscount = g.MemberId })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(g => new { id = g.id , mmbrscount = g.mmbrscount.Count() }).ToList();
```

but it gives me **unexpected result**

[image: unexpected]

However I did the same using ordinary sql query

```
select [postSubjectId] as postId, count([MemberId]) as mmbrsCount from [dbo].[Rooms] group by [postSubjectId]
```

and It gives me **result as expected**

[image: expected]

I need to apply that expected result using `LINQ GruoupBy extention method`

Answer (score 1):

So every `Room` has exactly one property `PostSubjectId`, and one string property `MemberId`.

> I need to get Grouped postSubjectId along with MemberId.Count()

Apparently you want to make groups of Rooms that have the same value for property `PostSubjectId` AND have the same value for MemberId.Count().

```
var result = dbContext.Rooms.GroupBy(room => new
{
    PostSubjectId = room.PostSucjectId,
    MemberIdLength = room.MemberId.Count(),
});
```

The result is a sequence of groups of Rooms. Every group has a key, which is a combination of [PostSubjectId, MemberIdLength]. The group is a sequence of Rooms. All rooms in one group have the same combination of [PostSubjectId, MemberIdLength].

If you don't want a `sequence of groups of Rooms`, you can use the [overload of GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__3_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___) that has a parameter resultSelector

```
var result = dbContext.Rooms.GroupBy(

// parameter keySelector
room => new
{   PostSubjectId = room.PostSucjectId,
    MemberIdLength = room.MemberId.Count(),
},

// parameter resultSelector:
// from every combination of [PostSubjectId, MemberIdLength] (= the key) and
// all rooms that have this combination, make one new object:
(key, roomsWithThisKey) => new
{
    // select the properties that you actually plan to use, for example
    PostSubjectId = key.PostSubjectId,
    MemberIdLength = key.MemberIdLength,

    RoomInformations = roomsWithThisKey.Select(roomWithThisKey => new
    {
        Id = roomWithThisKey.Id,
        Member = roomWithThisKey.Member,
        ...
    })
    .ToList(),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The grouping key `new { id = g.postSubjectId, mmbrscount = g.MemberId })` is like typing `group by [postSubjectId], count([MemberId])` in SQL.

The correct statement is:

```cs
_context.Rooms
    .GroupBy(r => r.postSubjectId)
    .Select(g => new 
    {
        id = g.Key,
        mmbrscount = g.Count()
    })
```